# How to set nginx friendly url with lang suffix?

Tags: php, html, nginx, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I wish to have multilanguage (php/html) site... but i'm very weak in nginx/rewrite
In the http address there are 3 variables (ln -language, page, step)

There is a problem when i write https://testpage.org.pl/esp/home
the "/esp/" - isnt recognized like $ln variable ...

how can i fix it?

here's my nginx rewrite:

```
rewrite ^/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /index.php?page=$1 last;
rewrite ^/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/step-([1-3])$ /index.php?page=$1&step=$2 last;
rewrite "^/([a-z]{2})/$" /index.php?ln=$1 last;
rewrite "^/([a-z]{2})/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$" /index.php?ln=$1&page=$2 last;
rewrite "^/([a-z]{2})/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/step-([1-3])$" /index.php?ln=$1&page=$2&step=$3 last;
```

Comment: Not sure what language `esp` represents, but the rewrite statements above are designed for ISO 639-1 language codes which contain a two character base. These are the same codes used in the HTTP request and HTML header.

Comment: its an hmtl/php website

Comment: Sorry, I thought your question related to human languages.

Comment: no problem... i thought that question tags are enought :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your language variable always has 2 or 3 characters, you can just change your rewrites with the language variable in it to:

```
rewrite "^/([a-z]{2,3})/$" /index.php?ln=$1 last;
rewrite "^/([a-z]{2,3})/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$" /index.php?ln=$1&page=$2 last;
rewrite "^/([a-z]{2,3})/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/step-([1-3])$" /index.php?ln=$1&page=$2&step=$3 last;
```

This will make sure it will only match a language with a length between 2 and 3 and will probably work fine in your case.